i want to be able to locate a cell that contains a certain string
Is there a function to be able to search through all of the cells in a Google sheet and have it return the cell that contains a certain string?  For example: each cell has 1 random word in it, I want to find the cell that contains the word Hello.
How would I go about this?  Thanks!

Assuming you want to return the address of the cell that's equal to "Hello" in Sheet1 you can use:
=LET(rng,Sheet1!A:ZZZ,TEXTJOIN(,1,ARRAYFORMULA(IF(rng="Hello",ADDRESS(ROW(rng),COLUMN(rng),4),))))


If you're using Apps Script, you can use the TextFinder class:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder
For ex:
//Find cells that contain "C"
let ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 .createTextFinder("C")
 .matchEntireCell(true)
 .matchCase(true)
 .matchFormulaText(false)
 .ignoreDiacritics(true)
 .findAll();

Source: https://spreadsheet.dev/find-and-replace-google-sheets-textfinder-apps-script
If you need a formula directly in the Sheets, you can try VLOOKUP https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en
